# UIViewのサブクラス時にrequire init()が必要な場合の理由

Tags: swift, xcode

XCodeでUIViewのサブクラスを作る際にrequire init()が必要な場合と必要ない場合はどのようなときでしょうか？

```
import UIKit

class MyUIView:UIView
{
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

同じUIViewのサブクラスでもrequired init()がない場合もあります。
必要な場合と必要で無い場合を教えていただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

簡単な答えとしては、「サブクラスで `convenience` でない `init` を実装する場合は必要。実装しない場合は必要ではない」です。

正確には
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html を完全に理解する必要があるのですが、

> Unlike subclasses in Objective-C, Swift subclasses do not inherit their superclass initializers by default.

Swift では、スーパークラスのイニシャライザを継承しないときがあります。というかデフォルトでは継承しません。

ですが、上記ドキュメントのAutomatic Initializer Inheritanceの項

> **ルール1**
>   サブクラスでDesignatedイニシャライザを定義しない場合はスーパークラスのすべてのDesignatedイニシャライザを継承します。

とあります。

`UIView` には 2 つのDesignatedイニシャライザがあり `init(frame:)` と `init?(coder:)` です。
また、`init?(coder:)` は `required` 指定されています。

`init(frame:)` をオーバーライド**しない**場合は、`init?(coder:)`を実装しなくても継承されるのですが、実装**する**場合は、`init?(coder:)` は継承されずに、無くなってしまいます。ところが、`init?(coder:)` は `required` 指定なので定義されていないとコンパイルが通りません。なので、カスタムの動作を加える否かに関わらず、実装しないとダメということになります。

逆に、`init?(coder:)` だけを実装することは可能なのですが、`init(frame:)` は継承されないので、下記コードはコンパイルできません。

```
class MyView : UIView {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

MyView(frame: CGRectZero) // init(frame:) が無い！
```

※ Xcode7 で `init(coder:)` は Failable initializer となったので `init?(coder:)` としています。